# Google Play Location Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called

Tags: java, android, location, google-play-services

I am getting very strange crash for some of my users. I am using Google Play Services and the Location service. The error is:

```
Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
```

The relevant function in the code that it says is causing the crash is:

```
  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

      if (debug) {
          Toast.makeText(this, DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Connected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      // Request location updates using static settings
      setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
      mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);<---- Crash here

  }
```

The strange thing is, I can't replicate this crash in my own testing, so I can't figure out why this would be happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put `mLocationClient.connect()` before your `requestLocationUpdates` method. Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. Giving it a test. Hoping it fixes the issue.

Comment: I don't understand you guys!!! Can't you see that he is requesting location updates INSIDE onConnected(), and onConnected() is only being called AFTER he has already called connect(). I am having the same issue and I don't understand what is going on!! I call connect() and INSIDE onConnected() I try to get the location, and it fails with this miserable error. Doesn't make any sense, it tells me to do something I'm ALREADY doing.